# Understanding Dense layer after Embedding Layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, nlp, word-embedding

I am having some problems to understand the functioning of a Dense layer handling text sequences. Let's imagine this simple case: I have two sentences and I assign integers to the words:

```
Sentence 1  I like cheese
Sentence 2  I like milk 

Sentence to sequence
Seq1    [1, 2, 3]
Seq2    [1, 2, 4]
```

Then we take the input (the integer sequences) and add them to a Embedding layer (random numbers in 2 dimensions):

```
Embedding matrix        

Term    Index   Vector
I       1       [0.2 0.6]
like    2       [0.7 0.1]
cheese  3       [0.4 0.5]
milk    4       [0.1 0.9]
```

Next step is to Flatten the sequences with the embeddings in order to make it 1D:

```
    Sequence to Embedding
    Seq1    [[0.2 0.6] [0.7 0.1] [0.4 0.5]]
    Seq2    [[0.2 0.6] [0.7 0.1] [0.1 0.9]]

    Flatten to 1D for Dense layer
    Seq1    [0.2 0.6 0.7 0.1 0.4 0.5]
    Seq2    [0.2 0.6 0.7 0.1 0.1 0.9]
```

Now we can use those arrays as input for the Dense layer, something that would look like this:

Dense layer of 3 units with input length of sequence. Dot product of the input sequence with the weights matrix of the dense layer.

[Dense layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oky8X.png)

```
    Dense layer                                             

    Seq1    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  ·   WH                   =     ZH   …
           0.2 0.6 0.7 0.1 0.4 0.5  ·   W1,1    W1,2    W1,3       +    
                                        W2,1    W2,2    W2,3        
                                        W3,1    W3,2    W3,3       BH   
                                        W4,1    W4,2    W4,3            
                                        W5,1    W5,2    W5,3            
                                        W6,1    W6,2    W6,3

    Seq2    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  ·   WH                   =     ZH   …
           0.2 0.6 0.7 0.1 0.1 0.9  ·   W1,1    W1,2    W1,3       +    
                                        W2,1    W2,2    W2,3        
                                        W3,1    W3,2    W3,3       BH   
                                        W4,1    W4,2    W4,3            
                                        W5,1    W5,2    W5,3            
                                        W6,1    W6,2    W6,3
```

The problem here is that every feature corresponds to one part of the sequence, X5 and X6 belong to the vector of the last word. Normally, with Bag of Words input **every X is assigned to a word**, and if the word is present then it gets a weight (following TF-IDF for example). Also with numerical data, Xi represents a feature (price, temperature, GDP...) and it is always that case. **Here**, however, **X is not assigned to a word and depends on the order**. See X5 and X6 how they change because the words are different.

**The weights in the Weight Matrix of the Dense layer are assigned to a feature (Xi)**, and then they are optimised.

---

**My question:**

**How does it work if the order of words changes all the time and Xi is referring to different words?**

I understand LSTMs and other recurrent networks can handle dynamic ordering, but **Dense layers seemed to me that could not work with sequential text and that the input should be fixed by One Hot vector or TF-IDF** for example. Still I have seen examples of models with Sentences to Sequences of Integers, Embedding, Flatten and Dense layer architectures, plus I have tried myself and I see it does work... I would really appreciate some explanation or correction in my flow of thinking. Thanks!

Comment: have you got the answer or it is still open for you ?

Comment: It's still open.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.
This is why in transformer architectures they added in positional embedding to encode the order of each word.

More generally speaking, the order and position of words can be encoded either through positional embedding or through neural network architectures (CNN, GRU).